# Select JSON objects and add new attribute

Tags: javascript, json

I am quite new to javascript and work with the following json. My challenge is that I want to:

```
1. call an attribute
2. add a new attribute
3. add a prefix to the Url attribute

{
  "currency": [
    {},
    {
      "Name": "Product 1",
      "Url": "/currencies/product1/",
      "Symbol": "PT1",
      "Price": "$767.7",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Product 1",
      "Url": "/currencies/product1/",
      "Symbol": "PT1",
      "Price": "$767.7",
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to access the `url` via `data.Url`, but only get unassigned back.

When adding an attribute my JSON should look like the following:

```
...
    {
      "Name": "Product 1",
      "Url": "/currencies/product1/",
      "Symbol": "PT1",
      "Price": "$767.7",
      "Market": "Europe"
    },
...
```

Any suggestion how to access the attribute and add a new one?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: In JS, there's only one [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Comment: @Teemu Basically I want to retrieve all the URLs from this JSON Obj and add to each "Sub-"Object an attribute.

Comment: Please re-read my comment, and follow the provided link. Make the difference between JS objects and JSON data exchange format clear, and edit the question to reflect what you really have.

Comment: to access, it would probably be something like this: data.currency[1].url ; currency[1] , with "1" being the index number or the item in the array. And to add new item, you will do something like this: data.currency[1].market = "Europe"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will do, hope it helps

```js
var data = {
  "currency": [
    {},
    {
      "Name": "Product 1",
      "Url": "/currencies/product1/",
      "Symbol": "PT1",
      "Price": "$767.7",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Product 1",
      "Url": "/currencies/product1/",
      "Symbol": "PT1",
      "Price": "$767.7",
    }
  ]
}

var urls = [];

data.currency.forEach(function(cur) {
    if (cur.Url) urls.push(cur.Url);
    cur.Market = "Europe";
});

console.log(urls);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thank you! If I want to run it with an index like `data.currency[m]`. Why doesn`t this work?

Comment: can you provide more more info for the object you want to traverse?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get your value because you need to assign the JSON to a variable first.

Lets breakdown your JSON. Then you will understand why your approach doesn't work.

In this explanation, we divide it into several levels.

**Level 1**

```
var data = {
    "currency": [...]
}
```

In this level, you can get the value of "currency" by this syntax

```
data.currency
```

**Level 2**

```
var data = {
    "currency": [
        {},
        {...},
        {...}
    ]
}
```

Turns out, `data.currency` is an array. Therefore, to access the value inside an array, you need to use array syntax. For example, if you want to get the 2nd item of `data.currency`, you do

```
data.currency[1]
```

**Level 3**

```
var data = {
    "currency": [
        {},
        {
            "Name": "Product 1",
            "Url": "/currencies/product1/",
            "Symbol": "PT1",
            "Price": "$767.7",
        },
        {
            "Name": "Product 1",
            "Url": "/currencies/product1/",
            "Symbol": "PT1",
            "Price": "$767.7",
        }
    ]
};
```

Now, `data.currency[1]` is an object. So you can continue using the object approach to get values. For example

```
data.currency[1].Url
```

If you want to add new attributes (i.e. "Market") to it, you can simply write

```
data.currency[1].Market = "..."
```

**Note**

1. You have an empty object at your `data.currency[0]`. If you want to loop through that, be careful because it might throw error if you try to get object data that is absent.

**To sum up**

```js
// Assigning JSON to a variable
var data = {
  "currency": [
    {},
    {
      "Name": "Product 1",
      "Url": "/currencies/product1/",
      "Symbol": "PT1",
      "Price": "$767.7",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Product 1",
      "Url": "/currencies/product1/",
      "Symbol": "PT1",
      "Price": "$767.7",
    }
  ]
};

var url = [];

// Assigning variable to data.currency
var cur = data.currency;

for (var m = 0; m < cur.length; m++){

  // To solve the problem stated in Note 1 above
  // by checking whether cur[m].Url is present.
  // If cur[m].Url is absent, that if-statement will be skipped.
  if (cur[m].Url){
    url.push(cur[m].Url);
  
    // To add new attribute
    cur[m].Market = "Europe";
  }
  
}

console.log(url);
console.log(data);
```

The approach I used was using for loop.

For other approach, see [AngYC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47130204/select-json-objects-and-add-new-attribute/47130245#47130245).